# delete duplicate on multidimensional array and take those having highest value in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, duplicates

Suppose I have this array

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 0
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000001
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 1
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000001
        [gross] => 44650000
        [vat] => 4465000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 2
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000001
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 0
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000002
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 1
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000002
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 0
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000003
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 0
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 2132134923102931
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000003
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )
```

What should I do in PHP to pick uniques based on `revision_no` `vendor_no` and `document_number`. And then for those having the same `vendor_no` and `document_number` take only the one having the highest `revision_no`.

So the result will be like:

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 2
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000001
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 1
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000002
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 0
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 311560353071000
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000003
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [revision_no] => 0
        [invoice_type] => PK
        [transaction_id] => 5
        [vendor_number] => 2132134923102931
        [document_number] => 010.000-12.00000003
        [gross] => 34650000
        [vat] => 3465000
    )
```

Comment: and your code is ....

Comment: Study this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: this expected value only takes account on unique `vendor_no` and `document_number`. if you take along `gross`, this should be five results

Comment: Function `sort()` does not help here. The OP asks for filtering.

Comment: "[...] and take those having highest value" -- `usort()` might not be a silly call prior to filtering/grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$output = array_reduce(
    $input,
    function (array $carry, array $item) {
        // generate the key to identify the duplicates
        // Add $item['gross'] if needed
        $key = $item['vendor_number'].'/'.$item['document_number'];

        // If this is the first appearance of the key
        // then add the value to the partial list and return it
        if (! isset($carry[$key])) {
            $carry[$key] = $item;
            return $carry;
        }

        // A previous revision exists    
        // Check values in $item against those already existing in the list
        $old = $carry[$key];
        if ($old['revision_no'] < $item['revision_no']) {
            // This is a new revision, replace the old one
            $carry[$key] = $item;
        }

        // Return $carry (updated or not)
        return $carry;
    },
    array()
);
```

This code does not preserve the keys from the original array. A solution that preserves the keys can be implemented in a similar fashion using [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).